How to selectiveley disable OSIV filter in Spring
How to selectively disable OSIV filter in Spring for piecemeal migrating a big app?
I know there is a property in Spring Boot to disable it globally (spring.jpa.open-in-view), but I would like to do it gradually endpoint by endpoint.

I do believe you just need to copy and paste spring-boot's JpaWebConfiguration configuration and slightly modify it, should get something like:
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnWebApplication(type = ConditionalOnWebApplication.Type.SERVLET)
@ConditionalOnClass(WebMvcConfigurer.class)
public class CustomOSIVConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor openEntityManagerInViewInterceptor() {
        return new OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor();
    }

    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer openEntityManagerInViewInterceptorConfigurer(OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor interceptor) {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {

            @Override
            public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
                registry.addWebRequestInterceptor(interceptor)
                        // setup path patters there
                        .addPathPatterns("...");
            }

        };
    }

}

